# Is there a redis library which handles the pipelining automatically?

Tags: java, redis, pipeline, datastore, jedis

I am looking at the possibility of triggering the redis command from the client as a normal api and the library can pipeline the commands into it and possibly reply asynchronously back. Any library for the Java would be highly appreciated.

Any pointers to opensource work on the same lines would also be of the great help.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea, your clinets threads will hang while waiting for your wrapper to send and process the pipeline. What is your usecase?

Comment: So the wrapper should push out the commands if a certain threshold of commands reached the wrapper, or a max timeout may be order of 3ms.
Idea is to optimize the number of commands sent to the data store, which is kind of vertical scaling

Answer (score 2):

Both popular Java Redis clients, [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) and [lettuce](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce) provide async/pipelining. See [here](https://github.com/mp911de/lettuce/wiki/Asynchronous-Connections) for an example. You get a `Future` after issuing commands so you can sync on your own or work with future callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

[Redisson](https://redisson.org) provides asynchronous pipeline in more convenient way. Here is code example:

```
RBatch batch = redisson.createBatch();
RFuture<String> mapFuture = batch.getMap("test").putAsync("2", "5");
RFuture<Long> longFuture = batch.getAtomicLongAsync("counter").incrementAndGetAsync();

List<?> res = batch.execute();
// or 
RFuture<List<?>> asyncRes = batch.executeAsync();
```

Asynchronous methods returns `RFuture` object which implements both [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) and [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interfaces.

Further, you can get result

`mapFuture.get()` result or `asyncRes.get()[0]`

Binding listeners:

```
future.whenComplete((res, exception) -> {

  // handle both result and exception

});

// or

future.thenAccept(res -> {

  // handle result

}).exceptionally(exception -> {

  // handle exception

});
```